# python - remove whitespaces that are not needed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some string:

```
"text text                  blabla bla "
```

I need

```
"text text blabla bla"
```

how can I remove unnecessary whitespaces in python?

I tried `replace()` but I dont know dynamically how many bad whitespaces are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `split` and then `join`:

```
>>> " ".join("text text                  blabla bla ".split())
'text text blabla bla'
```

You could also use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(" +"," ","text text                  blabla bla ").strip()
'text text blabla bla'
```

Or `join` and `re.findall`:

```
>>> ' '.join(re.findall("[^ ]+","text text                  blabla bla "))
'text text blabla bla'
```

Comment: dang it, didnot come to this thought.. beautiful, thanks

Comment: These are in order of best to worst haha

Comment: just note that your 2nd one should like the solution by @NPE, you need to strip the end space. But the first solution is the only one needed anyway

Comment: @jamylak Indeed (×2)

Answer (score 2):

Split the string then join it with one space each time

```
" ".join(myString.split())
```

(where myString is the string to clean up)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "text text                  blabla bla "
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s.strip())
'text text blabla bla'
```

Here, `s.strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespaces, and `r'\s+'` matches a sequence of one or more whitespaces (that then get replaced with a single space).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, replace will not work.
Use regular expression and `strip()` to remove white-spaces.

e.g.

```
import re
s = "text text                  blabla bla "
re.sub("[  ]+"," ", s).strip()
'text text blabla bla'
```

OR
Use spilt.

```
" ".join(s.split())
'text text blabla bla'
```